# Permutations of composition factors of a finite group of finite length.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, group-theory, permutations, group-extensions

Let $G$ be a finite group of length $\ell(G)=n$, if $H$ is a decomposition series for $G$, we denote by $L(H)$ the ordered set of its factors.

I'm trying to figure out if the set $X_G:=\{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n$| there exist $H,F$ two composition series for $G$ such that $L(F)=\sigma(L(H))\}$ is a group under some (resonable) additional conditions.

It's clear that identity is an element of $X_G$ and that $\forall\sigma\in X_G$, $\sigma^{-1}\in X_G$; the real problem is to establish when $X_G$ is closed under permutation product.

I haven't found any counter example yet.

Edit: @DerekHolt pointed out that, actually, the group $C_6\times\mathfrak{S}_3$ is a counter example.
I also noticed that for any finite abelian group $G$ of length $\ell(G)=n$, $X_G=\mathfrak{S}_n$. Moreover if $m$ is odd, then $X_{D_m}=\mathfrak{S}_{\ell(D_m)-1}$, where $D_m$ is the $m$-th dihedral group.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try $C_6 \times S_3$.

Comment: @CrSb0001 The OP is asking if $X_G$ is a group or not. Is there something vague about that?

Comment: @coiso because in the definition of $X_G$ there is symmetry between $F$ and $H$, thus I can write either $L(F)=\sigma(L(H))$ or $L(H)=\sigma^{-1}(L(F))$.